# How to make MySQL use less memory?

Tags: mysql, memory, out-of-memory

I'm trying to make a database update with Drush to a Drupal 7 site with just a few nodes and 85 modules... As the update dies almost every time is clear that, for a VPS with 512MB with it's containerized services (mysql, nginx, php-fpm, etc.), there isn't enough memory...

Everytime MySQL gets killed by the kernel as far I can understand from the logs:

> Out of memory: Kill process 4310 (mysqld)

My question is, how can I configure MySQL service to avoid it's "assassination"? What are the parameters in the MySQL configuration file to lower the memory consumption of the mysqld process?

I'm in DEV so I don't mind if the process becomes slow. I just want to know what parameters I have to tweak to survive the update process without increasing the memory.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are dozens of such parameters, you can find all of them with detailed description in the mysql [server system variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html) documentation. In general, look for variables that have the word `size` in them. In particular, check out `innodb_buffer_pool_size` because the default value is 128MB and the recommended value on a dedicated server is 80% of the physical memory.

Comment: 80% is too much for a tiny VM.

Comment: I did not say he should set it t 80%, I pointed out this particular setting gecause it is generally set to a high level because the recomjended setting is 80%.

Comment: Thanks. innodb_buffer_pool_size is the most important here. I couldn't get it to work with my config at first because MySQL was inside a docker container and my settings for the container were wrong. Now the container is reading the my.cnf file and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 33):

Only you need:

```
[mysqld]
performance_schema = off
```

Comment: this single one made the difference for me, reducing from 175M to 37M of actual memory used.

Comment: this is the best answer in the whole internet ever !

Comment: in which file is this parameter?

Comment: file is in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Comment: The Performance Schema provides a way to inspect internal execution of the server at runtime. You likely don't need it if your server is stable.

Comment: Mine went from 390M to 181M.

Answer (score 23):

My config in a 512 Mb RAM at Vultr, with Fedora 29 and MariaDB. Using about 26% of RAM.

```
[mysqld]
performance_schema = off
key_buffer_size = 16M
tmp_table_size = 1M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 1M
max_connections = 25
sort_buffer_size = 512K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
join_buffer_size = 128K
thread_stack = 196K
```

In small VPSs, don't forget to have a swap enabled. In Vultr, for example, the default is no swap. Same in Digital Ocean.

Comment: `query_cache_size`, `query_cache_limit` were removed in MySQL 8.

Comment: 512M sort buffer?!?

Comment: Hey, fixed! 512K

Answer (score 4):

This config working for me on VPS 512M, hope this helps...

```
[mysqld]
performance_schema = off
port = 3306
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

key_buffer_size = 16M
query_cache_size = 2M
query-cache-limit = 1M
tmp_table_size = 1M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 1M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 1M
max_connections = 25

sort_buffer_size = 512M
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
join_buffer_size = 128K
thread_stack = 196K
binlog_cache_size = 0M

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
#symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

Comment: Shouldn't query-cache-limit be query_cache_limit ?

Comment: You probably meant `sort_buffer_size = 512K` instead of `sort_buffer_size = 512M`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a VM with a minuscule 512MB of RAM?  And you are running multiple things (Drupal, MySQL)?  You will be lucky to get it to work at all.  These setting *may* suffice to shrink MySQL enough to run:

```
key_buffer_size = 5M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 60M
```

Meanwhile, do not increase any values in my.cnf.  If my suggestions are not enough; let's see all of your my.cnf; there may be other things that can reasonably be decreased.

Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Thanks Rick. MySQL wasn't reading my "my.cnf" file, that made me doubt about what I have to tweak in order to make it work. MySQL was inside a docker container and the config wasn't right. MySQL could work perfectly with low memory consumption in a DEV environment.

Answer (score 0):

**I know that question is not related to docker**, but in case of someone is using **mysql with docker**, I was able to run a mysql container in a **very cheap server** with **512 mb**.

I used these docker-compose parameters based on @Hossein answer: `mysqld --performance_schema=off`

```
services:
  mysql57:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: mysqld --performance_schema=off
    container_name: mysql57
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
     - /opt/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: changeme
      MYSQL_USER: usr_acme
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: changeme
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_acme
      TZ: America/Lima
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 400M
```

Before this, without `mysqld --performance_schema=off`, server got very slow and after some minutes, nobody could connect.

You can add more parameters in command in order to reduce the ram/cpu usage:

```
command:
  - "mysqld"
  - "--performance_schema=off"
  - "--query_cache_size=2M"
  - "--query_cache_limit=1M"
  - "--foo=bar"
```

Comment: Docker also allows you to mount a custom my.cnf config, I highly recommend to do it. More readable and handy.